# An issue identifying Clifford Algebra with Endomorphism ring.

Tags: representation-theory, mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras

I am trying to work through pages 303-305 of Fulton and Harris and have ran into a problem. I will first give a little bit of setup to try and make this post self contained.

Let $V$ be an even dimensional complex vector space and $Q$ the standard non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V$. We form the Clifford algebra $\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)$. This algebra splits up into even and odd parts: $\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)=\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}\oplus\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{odd}}$, as does the exterior algebra: $\wedge^{\star}W=\wedge W^{\text{even}}\oplus\wedge W^{\text{odd}}$.

With this choice of dimension and bilinear form, $V$ splits up into maximal isotropic subspaces: $V=W\oplus W'$. Following Fulton and Harris I have then been able to show that we have an isomorphgism of algebras:
$$
\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)\cong\text{End}\left(\wedge^{\star}W\right)
$$

Fulton and Harris claim that from this decomposition and the above isomorphism that we have:

$$
\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}\cong\text{End}\left(\wedge W^{\text{even}})\oplus\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{odd}}\right)
$$

and this is where I get stuck. I proceeded as follows:

$$
\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)
\cong
\text{End}\left(\wedge^{\star}W\right)
\cong
\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{even}}\oplus\wedge W^{\text{odd}})
\cong
\text{End}\left(\wedge W^{\text{even}})\oplus\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{odd}}\right)
$$

This is obviously not correct, since it would imply that $\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)\cong \mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}$. I would really appreciate it if anybody could point out where I've gone wrong.

EDIT.

Thanks to David Hill I have realised thast the identification:
$$
\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{even}}\oplus\wedge W^{\text{odd}})
\cong
\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{even}})\oplus\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{odd}})
$$
was incorrect. This can be seen by either noting that $\text{dim}\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{even}}\oplus\wedge W^{\text{odd}})=2^{2n}$, while $\text{dim}\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{even}})\oplus\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{odd}})=2^{2n-1}$, or by noting the existence of odd homomorphisms such as $f_{w}:\wedge^{\text{even}}W\to\wedge^{odd}W$, $u\mapsto wu$ for $w\in W$.

This means that so far I have only established the following isomorphism:
$$
\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}\oplus\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{odd}}
\cong
\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{even}}\oplus\wedge W^{\text{odd}})
$$

I still need to somehow "split up", $\text{End}(\wedge W^{\text{even}}\oplus\wedge W^{\text{odd}})$, and "project out", the odd part of the Cifford algebra, but I am not sure how to go about this. Fulton and Harris claim that this can be done by noting that $\mathcal{Cl}(W)^{\text{even}}$ respects the splitting $\wedge^{\star}W=\wedge W^{\text{even}}\oplus\wedge W^{\text{odd}}$, but I am not sure exactly what that means. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think your last isomorphism is right--there are odd homomorphisms from $\wedge W^{even}$ to $\wedge W^{odd}$.

Comment: Thank you, I have realised that I had just been thinking of $\wedge W^{\text{even}}$ and $\wedge W^{\text{odd}}$ as vector spaces instead of algebras.  I now realise that the endomorphisms don't split up that simply.

Comment: Even for vector spaces, not every matrix is block diagonal.

Comment: Thats a good point! You have helped me correct a fundamental misunderstanding about vector spaces. Do you have any insights about my remaining issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I have figured this out. First of all, by decomposing an endomorphism into block digonal and block anti-diagonal parts one can show that for $n$-dimensional algebras $V_{1},V_{2}$:

$$
\text{End}(V_{1}\oplus V_{2})
\cong
\text{End}(V_{1})
\oplus
\text{End}(V_{2})
\oplus
\text{Hom}(V_{1},V_{2})
\oplus
\text{Hom}(V_{2},V_{1})
$$

and so:

$$
\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}
\oplus
\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{odd}}
\cong
\left(
\text{End}(\wedge^{\text{even}}W)
\oplus
\text{End}(\wedge^{\text{odd}}W)
\right)
\oplus
\left(
\text{Hom}(\wedge^{\text{even}}W,\wedge^{\text{odd}}W)
\oplus
\text{Hom}(\wedge^{\text{odd}}W,\wedge^{\text{even}}W)
\right)
$$

Let $\phi$ be the above isomorphism (it is given explicitly in Fulton and Harris). On can then show directly that $\phi$ respects this direct sum decomposition. Explicitly we have:
$$
\phi|_{\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}}:\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}\to\text{End}(\wedge^{\text{even}}W)
\oplus
\text{End}(\wedge^{\text{odd}}W)
$$
and
$$
\phi|_{\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{odd}}}:\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{odd}}\to\text{Hom}(\wedge^{\text{even}}W,\wedge^{\text{odd}}W)
\oplus
\text{Hom}(\wedge^{\text{odd}}W,\wedge^{\text{even}}W)
$$
And from here, since $\phi=\phi|_{\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}}\oplus\phi|_{\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{odd}}}$, we see that both restrictions must be isomorphisms.

I think that my main difficulty with this problem was a findamental misunderstanding of the Endomorphism ring as pointed out by David Hill. Beyond that, working out an explicit example for $V=\mathbb{C}^{4}$ helped me realise that $\phi$ respects the $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ grading of the Clifford algebra.

Comment: You’re almost right, but the direct sum decomposition implies the summands commute, which is not true of diagonal & anti-diagonal parts in matrix multiplication.

Comment: Oh, in that case what would be the correct decomposition? Would it still include $\text{End}(V_{1})\oplus \text{End}(V_{2})$, or would I instead have to show that the restriction of $\phi$ to the Even part of the Clifford algebra surjects onto $\text{End}(V_{1})\oplus \text{End}(V_{2})\subseteq\text{End}(V_{1}\oplus V_{2})$. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: As a vector space, your decomposition is correct. It's just that, as an algebra, you would represent an element of $End(V_1\oplus V_2)$ as a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\phi_{11}&\phi_{12}\\\phi_{21}&\phi_{22}\end{bmatrix}$, where $\phi_{ij}:V_i \to V_j$ is a homomorphism, and you would multiply elements according to matrix multiplication.

Comment: I see. Then the elements of $\text{End}(V_{1,2})$ are represented by your $\phi_{11}$'s and $\phi_{22}$'s, and form a subalgebra $\text{End}(V_{1})\oplus\text{End}(V_{2})\subseteq \text{End}(V_{1}\oplus V_{2})$ which can be identified with $\mathcal{Cl}(V,Q)^{\text{even}}$, is that correct?

Comment: I think that what you are meaning to say is correct, but I’m not sure about the first part where you use the notation $V_{1,2}$.

Comment: That was just intended as a shorthand for "$\text{End}(V_{1})$ and $\text{End}(V_{2})$", but perhaps the notation is not so standard.

Thanks again for all your help. If you repost any of your comments as an answer I would be happy to award you the bounty.